# My vim directory is in a weird place, should it be moved?

Tags: macos, vim

So I wanted to set up my new PC and vim was one of the first things.

I need my .vim directory for that. I have vim and it works, too.

I found the indent folder at `/usr/share/vim/vim90/indent`. This seems to be the correct folder but I have no idea if this is the correct location. The .vimrc i created at ~/.vimrc.

There are as far as I could find two possible "proper" places for .vim, which is ~/.vim and /etc/vim. It is in neither.

What should be the next step to properly use vim? Should I leave it there? Should I create .vim in my home dir and move it there? Does it literally not matter and I am confusing over nothing?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: its ~/.vimrc. .....

Comment: You're likely worrying over nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/usr/share/vim/vim90/` is the system-wide "runtime directory". What is in there shouldn't be messed with because…

- it needs to be in a certain state for Vim to work as expected,
- whatever you do there might be overridden or left behind during later upgrade,
- other users might be negatively impacted by your changes.

The first reason is sad, but yeah, Vim is a fragile beast, the working of which can be compromised very easily by moving stuff around, renaming files or whatnot.

The second reason is, I think, easy to demonstrate: when 9.1 is released, it will ignore `/usr/share/vim/vim90/` entirely, and thus whatever changes you might have done there.

The third reason might seem more abstract because you are probably the only actual *person* to use that particular computer, but Unix-like systems are multi-user by design and, in that context, keeping *your* changes in *your* own `$HOME` is just common sense.

Vim is highly configurable and offers many ways to craft the perfect personal environment… or shoot yourself in the foot so, *for now*, you should **do your configuration in *your* own `$HOME`** as it is simple and predictable:

- create a `.vim` directory under `$HOME`, `$HOME/.vim`,
- create a `.vimrc` file under `$HOME`, `$HOME/.vimrc`,

and forget that `/usr/share/vim/vim90/` ever existed.

Comment: neat, thank you! so ~/.vim, do i need to do anything there to get it to run? Does it run on its own/does vim check for this location? if i were to put packages in there, would they work just outofthebox?

Comment: `~/.vim` is your runtime directory but it is not a dumpster. Vim knows about that directory and it expects its content to be organized in a certain way so you will still have to be careful. Configuring vim is introduced in chapter 5 of the user manual. Read it carefully, follow the tags, etc. `:help user-manual`.